# How to dynamically display part of webpage using angularJs

Tags: html, angularjs, rest

I have a `angular js` application, in which I am retrieving `http response` data using rest services. I want to conditionally display the part of the page. For eg: if the response data in angular is "manager" , the page should have different options displayed and if the response data is "employee" , same part of webpage should display different options. 
How do I do that?
This is single page application.

Comment: Any intro-level angular tutorial will show you some of the dozens of different ways this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement you can use [ng-switch directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch). The ngSwitch directive is used to conditionally swap DOM structure on your template based on a scope expression.

For your example:

```
<div ng-switch="expression">
  <div ng-switch-when="manager">...</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="employee">...</div>
</div>
```

Here `expression` will contain info you get from response data of either `manager or employee`.

Hope this will be helpful to you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-show directive like:

```
<div>
    <div ng-show="employeeType == 'Manager'">    </div>
    <div ng-show="employeeType == 'employee'">    </div>
<div>
```

For more information refer to this link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow